# BeautifulSoup: An issue with find_all() and unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

So I'm using BeautifulSoup to build a webscraper to grab every ad on a Craigslist page. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import bs4

page = "http://miami.craigslist.org/search/roo?query=brickell"
search_html = requests.get(page).text

roomSoup = BeautifulSoup(search_html, "html.parser")

ad_list = roomSoup.find_all("a", {"class":"hdrlnk"})
#print ad_list
ad_ls = [item["href"] for item in ad_list]
#print ad_ls
ad_urls = ["miami.craigslist.org" + ad for ad in ad_ls]
#print ad_urls 
url_str = [str(unicode) for unicode in ad_urls]

# What's in url_str?
for url in url_str:
    print url
```

When I run this, I get:

> miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870912192.html
>   miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4858122981.html
>   miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870665175.html
>   miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4857247075.html
>   miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870540048.html ...

This is exactly what I want: a list containing the URLs to each ad on the page.

My next step was to extract something from each of those pages; hence building another BeautifulSoup object. But I get stopped short:

```
for url in url_str:
    ad_html = requests.get(str(url)).text
```

Here we finally get to my question: What exactly is this error? The only thing I can make sense of is the last 2 lines:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "webscraping.py", line 24,
 in <module>
     ad_html = requests.get(str(url)).text   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py",
 line 65, in get
     return request('get', url, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py",
 line 49, in request
     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
 line 447, in request
     prep = self.prepare_request(req)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
 line 378, in prepare_request
     hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",
 line 303, in prepare
     self.prepare_url(url, params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",
 line 360, in prepare_url
     "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url)) requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL
 u'miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870912192.html': No schema supplied.
 Perhaps you meant http://miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870912192.html?
```

It looks like the issue is that all my links are preceded by u', so requests.get() isn't working. This is why you see me pretty much trying to force all the URLs into a regular string with str(). No matter what I do, though, I get this error. Is there something else I'm missing? Am I completely misunderstanding my problem?

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misundersood the problem

The message:

```
 u'miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870912192.html': No schema supplied.
 Perhaps you meant http://miami.craigslist.org/mdc/roo/4870912192.html?
```

means it lacks of `http://` (the schema) before the url

so replacing

```
ad_urls = ["miami.craigslist.org" + ad for ad in ad_ls]
```

by

```
ad_urls = ["http://miami.craigslist.org" + ad for ad in ad_ls]
```

should do the job

Comment: That did the trick. I was completely overlooking that. Thanks!